# Simulate a click on an anchor with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

i have a problem calling a function with jquery.
Currently i use an a lot of anchor to display different section of my web page. 
The anchor are structured in this way:

```
<a id="ps1">PS1</a>
<a id="ps2">PS2</a>
<a id="ps3">PS3</a>
<a id="ps4">PS4</a>
```

And the Jquery code are this:

```
 $("#ps1").click(function() {
   $("#box_dati_profilo").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_contatti_profilo").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_tour").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_mappa").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_galleria").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_stato_account").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_biografia").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_orari").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#impostazioni").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#documenti").hide("fast", function() {});
   $("#box_anteprima_profilo").fadeIn("fast", function() {});
 });
```

Now, what i want to do is this: if a $_GET variable are setted (possible values are ps1,ps2,ps3,ps4) i call the click on the ps1 or ps2 etc automatically..it is possible?

EDIT
I've tried with this:

```
$("#<?php echo $_GET['tab'];?>").click();
```

but it wont work..

Comment: `$_GET` not getting set..

Comment: Is your `$("#<?php echo $_GET['tab'];?>").click();` just in a script, or inside jquery startup: `$(function() { $("#<?php echo $_GET['tab'];?>").click(); });`

Comment: just in a script before of the first jquery code that i've posted above

Comment: Do you have a live demo or a fiddle to test it on?

Comment: And what's the rendered output (open page, view source) for that line?

Comment: The browser show this: 
<script>
    $("#ps3").click();
</script>

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola just curious, do you have an event set up for #ps3 click?
Btw. make sure your click event is bound to the element BEFORE you trigger it.

Comment: "just in a script before of the first jquery code" - as @PatrickSchumacher points out, this needs to be *after* you have bound the click event.  Move the `.click()` to the end of your script/after the setup

Comment: you were right...with the code after the click() it work..thank guys!

Comment: Always check by loading the page, wait a second or so, then open the browser console and enter the js in the console ?  If that works, then it's in the wrong place in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can trigger a click like this

```
$( "#ps1" ).click();
```

You need to make sure that anchor tag has already loaded before you `bind` `click` and invoke this `click`

```
$("<?php echo $_GET['tab'];?>").click(); //remove the extra # after first double quote
```

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola what does #<?php echo $_GET['tab'];?> generate? also did you ensured that bind of event happened after your content was loaded and before your click was triggered?

Comment: it generate  #ps1 or #ps2 or #ps3 or #ps4

Comment: @RayonDabre it is setted

Comment: Try this: `window.location.href.split('#').pop();`

Comment: @freedomn-m you mean he should do $("<?php echo $_GET['tab'];?>").click(); and remove the extra # after first double quote? I guess you are right.